# Cannot Save Product Error : These is no live transactions. After Uploading 4000 products

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

Today, I have came across a very unusual problem, I firstly upload 4000 products by using the following script:

```
foreach ($xmlData as $orderwiseData) {

    $counter = $counter + 1 ;
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->setSku($orderwiseData->vad_variant_code);
    $product->setName($orderwiseData->vad_description);
    $product->setDescription($orderwiseData->vad_description);

    $product->setShortDescription('');
    $product->setPrice(floatval($orderwiseData->vafp_rsp_inc_vat));
    $product->setTypeId('simple');
    $product->setWeight(floatval($orderwiseData->vad_weight));
    $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // need to look this up
    $product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
    $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
    $product->setStatus(1); // enabled
    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));

    $stockData = $product->getStockData();
    print get_class($stockData);
    var_dump($stockData);
    $stockData['qty'] = (int) $orderwiseData->vasq_free_stock_quantity;
    $product->setStockData($stockData);

    $product->save();

    echo $counter . "   ";
    echo "importing    ". $orderwiseData->vad_variant_code."\n";
```

}

The import complete successfully and I can see the product from the backend. I then realised I missed around 100 product so I restart the product import by using the above script again, but this time, $product->save() seems to drop exception that :

```
2014-08-25T16:13:40+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in /home/veronica/development/cotswold/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:322
Stack trace:
#0 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(322): PDO->rollBack()
#1 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(524): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_rollBack()
#2 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(258): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->rollBack()
#3 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(124): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->rollback()
#4 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(326): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->rollBack()
#5 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(728): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#6 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#7 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#8 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/veronica/development/cotswold/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

I have sent like 30 hours on this, but cannot get to anywhere. At the beginning, I was suspecting it is the Stock array doing this error as the product stock array contain 5 data, I have only imported like 1 in the above script, but this database issue continue to occur after I fix the product stock array issue.

Now I am very sure, this is database issue, I took the database backup before the product import, everything works fine, but I need to fix this error.

This is on Magento Version 1.9.0.1.

If anyone gentleman have dealt with this issue before, please advise, thank you for all the support.

Comment: did you put any limit on that??

Comment: thanks for your replays, could you be more specific, which limit ?

Comment: see some products are already being created so when you run script again ,it finds same data .. so either delete all the product or put check on product id